# API status response for partial data being fetched from db?

Tags: api-design

What would be appropriate status response in the case if client requested specific range of entries like so.

`GET /cars?ids=1,2,3,4,5`

And the database returned only part of the collection, so the client will get only.

`['car1', 'car2', car4']`

I'm hesitating between 202 and 206. But what would be more or less standard way dealing with such situation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you should go with the 206.

202 is for

> Its purpose is to allow a server to accept a request for some other process (perhaps a batch-oriented process that is only run once per day) without requiring that the user agent's connection to the server persist until the process is completed.

206 is used when

> The server has fulfilled the partial GET request for the resource.

Which is your case.

Read the specs : https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7233#section-4.1

Comment: 2616 is obsolete. The appropriate RFCs are 7230-7235

Comment: Updated the specs link. Thanks @Eric Stein

Comment: Going with 206 for now, although I do realize it is not what it is aimed for and not what it is about... will probably switch to custom error code later on in the game. Thanks for @Ian Boyd suggestion.

Answer (score 1):

The 202 code is intended for use with *range fetching*; where the browser asks the server to fetch a range of bytes of a response.

You might consider a (custom) 300-level code:

> 10.3 Redirection 3xx
>
> This class of status code indicates that further action needs to be taken by the user agent in order to fulfill the request.

Unfortunately, like the standard 200-level codes, none of them satisfy your situation of *a partial list of responses*.

The **202** code conceptually is used to indicate that the server has *accepted what you sent, and is now going to go away and process it* (asynchronously):

> The request has been accepted for processing, but the processing has not been completed. There is no facility for re-sending a status code from an asynchronous operation such as this.

I would tend away from the 200 code, as the operation the browser asked for was not completed. A 300 code is more appropriate to tell a client, who issued a perfectly reasonable request, that the server wasn't able to complete all of it - and the browser will have to do more work to get the complete set of results.

Comment: Thanks for showing another perspective, now I'm scratching my head even harder.

Comment: It's not horrible to create your own 2xx or 3xx code when none of the existing codes fit. Your http response is still going to give the error description: e.g. `312 PARTIAL RESULTS`. Since you define the API, you get to define what `312` means. But i do applaud your trying to find the best *standard* code. The http codes cover a lot of situations, and usually there's one that will work. But this is a unique situation.